# How to pass query search keywords in solr-node client-side application so that my application can interact with Apache Solr collection?

Tags: javascript, solr

I am doing a small project to retrieve some search results by using Apache Solr instances. In my client-side application, I am using solr-node to interact with Solr from Node.js. The code is as follows:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// add Apache Solr and integrate it with node.js
const SolrNode = require('solr-node');

const client = new SolrNode({
  host:'localhost',
  port:'8983',
  core:'mycollection',
  protocol:'http'
});


app.get('/search', (req, res) => {

  const strNewQuery = client.query()
  .q('text: searchkeyword')
  .addParams({
    wt: 'json',
    indent: true
  });


  client.search(strNewQuery, (err, result) => {

    if (err) {
              console.error('Error querying Solr:', err);
              res.status(500).send('Error querying Solr');
              res.redirect('/');
    } else {
          //    res.json(result.response.docs);
              console.log('Response: ', result.response);
              console.log('node.js fetching is successful!');
 
              const formattedResults = result.response.docs.map((doc) => ( {
                id: doc.id,
                titile: doc.filename
              }));

              res.render("list", {listTitle: "Probe Search Result", newListItems: formattedResults});

    }
  });
  

});

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
  res.render("about");
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Start the Server
const port = 3030;

app.listen(port, ()=> {
  console.log('Solr-node server listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

Here, I hardcode my search key word as variable, strNewQuery so that if I run the url, "http"//localhost:3030/search", the response results from my Apache Solr instance will be displayed in the webpage. I use list.ejs to display my results. The solr-node works very well with my own solr collection and I compared my solr-node results with Solr Admin results. They look good.
However, hardcoded search word is just a mockup test, not my target. How can I pass my query search keyword from the HTML input form to my solr-node server from my client-side program? To resolve this, I did the following codes:

```js
//filename: clientSolr.js, given in the <script> part in HTML
  const solr = require('solr-client');      

  // create a Solr client
  const client = solr.createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8983,
    core: 'mycollection',
    protocol: 'http'
  });

  //Handle form submission
  document.getElementById('searchForm').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const query = document.getElementById('queryInput').value;

    try {
      // Execute Solr query
      const response = await client.search(query, { wt: 'json' }); // Specify JSON response format
      const docs = response.response.docs; // Extract search results

      const formattedResults = result.response.docs.map((doc) => ( {
            id: doc.id,
            titile: doc.filename
          }));

      formattedResults.forEach((formatResult) => {
            console.log('result id: ', formatResult.id);
            console.log('result filename: ', formatResult.filename);
          });

      // Display results
      const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
      resultsDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results
      docs.forEach((doc) => {
        resultsDiv.innerHTML += `<p>${doc.id}</p>`; // Display relevant data (adjust as needed)
      });
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.error('Error fetching Solr data:', error);
    }
 });

//  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Search Solr client Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" id="queryInput" placeholder="Enter your search query">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="clientSolr.js">
    
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here, I use solr-client library in my client-side javascript and retrieve the query keyword by identifying the element id from my HTML. But these codes didn't work. I knew I can not use global variable, document, to retrieve the elementId in the node.js code because backend side does not recognize the document. My question is how can I pass query search keywords in solr-node program even though node.js DOES NOT recognize the global variable, document. I knew the differences between solr-client and solr-node but it seems that both are not able to handle the query search keyword from HTML input form. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a HTML page with some JS running in your browser (PAGE).

Then you have some NodeJS code running on your server, listening on port 3030 (NODE).

Finally you have Solr running (SOLR).

Now, you alredy have a working NODE->SOLR connection. What you did wrong was to put the Solr client code in your PAGE. It should only run on your NODE server.

So your PAGE code must pass the text from the query box and pass it to NODE as  e.g. a request parameter: `http://localhost:3030/search?myQuery=hello`. Next you will have to pull out that request parameter from `req` on your NODE server, and pass it further to Solr.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to pass query keyword input from HTML form to the node server. It worked.